# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Access localhost from phone/PC in same network

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, localhost

I am building an ASP.NET MVC 5 application and I run the server locally and it works fine, but I can't seem to connect to it from an external device.

The URL is `localhost:60884` . I navigate with my phone to `<internal_IP_address>:60884` and I get a `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error.

I have disabled the firewall and I have tried to connect the PC on my phone's WiFi HotSpot, but no success.

Can someone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: A localhost bound IP won't expose to the external network so you would need to change the binding to something other than localhost...

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Take a look at - https://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer might be of help...

Comment: Tried that and it didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by setting it up in project properties. In Visual Studio if you go into the Web tab on the right, there'll be a Start URL you can choose

Whatever address you put in there you should be able to navigate to on your phone, provided you're on the same network. You are likely getting the timeout error because your device can't connect to the server's address at all.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't see a Web tab, where is it? I am using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: I saw it and changed it, but still nothing.